# Proof of $\left|\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac{k!}{N^k}-\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{kN}\right|\le\dfrac{1}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Is it possible to prove the following inequality?
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac{k!}{N^k}-\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{kN}\right|\le\dfrac{1}{4}$$
Thanks

Comment: Is this for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @dleggas No, just for $N=65537$

Comment: If you introduce $u_{N} = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{k !}{N^{k}}$ and $v_{N} = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{k N}$, you can see that we have $0 \leq u_{n} $ and $0 \leq v_{n}$, that $u_{n} \to 0$ and $v_{n} \to 0 $ as $n \to + \infty$. Finally, for $n \geq 3$, $u_{n}$ and $v_{n}$ are decreasing sequences. As a consequence, you only need to check your inequality for $n \lesssim 30$. And the inequality is *saturated* for $n = 2$.

Comment: @Alittlelime: the plot shows the limit of the series for $N\to\infty$ goes to zero, so I suppose $N=65537$ is incorrect

Comment: To complement my previous comment, your inequality is very crude. One could be interested for example at the *asymptotic behavior* of $|u_{N} - v_{N}|$ for $N \to +\infty$. What value of $\beta > 0$ could we choose in order to have asymptotically $|u_{N} - v_{N}| \leq C N^{- \beta}$ ?

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra It was obviously a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. First use triangle inequality:

$\displaystyle |\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac{k!}{N^k}-\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{kN}| \le  |\sum_{k=31}^{N}\frac{k!}{N^k}|+|\sum_{k=31}^{N}\frac{1}{kN}|+\sum_{k=1}^{30} \frac{k!}{N^{k}}+\frac{1}{kN}$

1)$\sum_{k=1}^{30} \frac{k!}{N^{k}}+\frac{1}{kN}$ is small when $N$ is large.

2)$\displaystyle |\sum_{k=31}^{N}\frac{k!}{N^k}| \le |\sum_{k=31}^{N}\frac{k!}{k^k}| \le |\sum_{k=31}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{k^k}|\le |\sum_{k=31}^{\infty}\frac{2}{k^2}|$

Last inequality is from $\displaystyle \frac{n!}{n^n} \le \frac{2}{n^2}$ (it's very easy to show).

3)$\displaystyle |\sum_{k=31}^{N}\frac{1}{kN}| \le |\sum_{k=31}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}| $

Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, so $\sum_{n=30}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ is small (see [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20n%3D31%20to%20infty%20%281%2Fn%29%5E2)).